# How to deliver arguments to a callback function?

Tags: ros, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I am relatively new user of ROS, and would be grateful if you could answer to my question.
I work with Linux and C, and I want to deliver arguments to my callback function.
Lets say I want to deliver to it the next struct as a parameter:

```
typedef struct imageManagmentStruct
{
    IplImage*  pSrcIplImage;
    IplImage*  pDstIplImage;
    GdkPixbuf* pGtkPixbuf;
    GtkWidget* pGtkImgWindow;    
    int        previousImageSize;
    int        left_attach;
    int        right_attach;
    int        top_attach;
    int        bottom_attach;    
} ImageManagmentStruct;

My callback is:

void imageCallback ( const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg,
                     ImageManagmentStruct* pToImageManagmentStruct
                   )
{
    // My code.
}

The call to the callback from the main done like this:

ros::Subscriber subLeft = nh.subscribe ("/bb2/left/image_raw", 10, imageCallback,  
                                        pointerToImageManagmentStruct);
```

And this is not compiling...

Thank you all,
Felix.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12045/how-to-deliver-arguments-to-a-callback-function?/) by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 378 on 2011-11-22

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, if it can work like this. The extra parameter is usually for callbacks that are member functions.

What you want is to use boost::bind.

Your subscriber call should look like this:

```
ros::Subscriber subLeft = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image> ("/bb2/left/image_raw", 10,
    boost::bind(imageCallback, _1, pointerToImageManagmentStruct) );
```

(untested, but the call should be similar to this)

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on 2011-11-22**:
Hi,I wanted to say thank you for your answer. Just for others that will read this posts I want to be a little more precise. The exact line for my case is: ros::Subscriber subLeft = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image> ("/bb2/left/image_raw", 10, boost::bind(imageCallback, _1, pointerToImageManagmentStruct ); While the call for imageCallback is exactly the same as I have written in the original post.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-01-24**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/63991/how-to-make-callback-function-called-by-several-subscriber/?answer=63998#post-id-63998 shows the code for a class method callback